# dbfit - How to assert that an item is not returned in the results

Tags: testing, automation, fitnesse, dbfit

I am creating dbfit test cases and I encountered a scenario where I need to check that an item is not included in the results returned by the query. How can I do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you carry out a query to count the number of records that are matching your query then you can check that the result is zero something like

|query |select count(id) as NumberOfRecords from dbo.tablename where criteria='matched'|
|NumberOfRecords                                                                |
|0                                                                              |

Comment: Yes that would work. Thanks. However, If I am executing a Stored Procedure and I want to validate that it is not returning a specific record, this solution wouldn't work